# How do you find highest value in the list then increase it with the other values increasing as well expect a value that is set as 0

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python program that reads a list then raises all values one by one until they reach a specific value in this case 8 being the value I want to reach, my goal is to raise a list of 9 values varying from 0 to 8 but not raising any values in the 0 field, am sort of new to programming and have yet to find a solution I started learning python a few days ago and want to make my first program, this is what I've got so far

```
drawbarstring = input("Put your drawbar string here(9 digits): ")
drawbarmain = list(map(int, str(drawbarstring)))
```

I am clueless on what to do next any advice on this the goal of this program is to in the end when I type a 9 value string check all values and raise it until one peak at 8 but not raising any zeroes as they don't count in the use case am using, the reason am rating all the others is my script is intended to assist me making patches for drawbar organs drawbars that max volume by typing a value than having the script raise all of them until one peak at 8 value than giving me the result so I can apply it in the organ, hopefully, this enough info and can be useful in assisting me and others that might have the problem I do
example of input and output code, the value could like this 327645222 or 004544220 in the case of the 2nd we would skip the values that are 0 but in the first case we would find the highest and raise them all until the highest of the values reaches 8 then the others would be raised the same number of times, for example, an if it was 4 raises until the highest hits 8 the others would be as well, I hope this makes it clear

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some example input and output?  It's not quite clear to me exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: sure thing i can try and edit it

Comment: Use `max(drawbarmain)` to get the highest digit. Subtract that from 8 to get the increment amount. Then use a list comprehension to add that to all the digits except 0: `[num + inc if num > 0 else num for num in drawbarmain]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do it.

```
drawbarstring = input("Put your drawbar string here(9 digits): ")
drawbarmain = list(map(int, str(drawbarstring)))

def compute_nums(drawbarmain):
    for i in range(len(drawbarmain)):
        for x in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[x] == 8:
                return drawbarmain

        for j in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[j-1] < 8 and drawbarmain[j] != 0:
                drawbarmain[j] += 1
            else:
                break



print(compute_nums(drawbarmain))
```

I used a function because it is very simple to cancel a function by using "return" if a number hits 8.

Also, in the third `for` loop, I used `[j-1]` because that's the number that I changed before, and we know that `j` can't be 8 because of the second `for` loop making sure that none of the existing numbers are 8s.

Comment: well i tried this function today as yesterday I had not much free time and it seems the result is a bit buggy half of it works correctly while other half does not, I tried a simple 8 1s in a row as that way i can sure if the scaling is done right and it resulted in "[8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7]" witch instead should be a total of 8 number 8, i wonder whats doing that i might need help again, edit, i forgot on the original post drawbars are 8 digits and not nine my bad

Comment: it seems my math was wrong it was 9 numbers instead of 8 but the output still wrong with 9 numbers no matter what simple values i type in to test

Comment: I think this answer misunderstands the requirements.

Comment: i was busy last day with something and did a quick check without really looking but now i got on my other post somethat might be enough to give me enough info to try and solve it on my own i shall update that post when am done with my own code

Comment: well i managed to fix a small part but just have to figure why last part is not doing what i need all numbers now scale properly expect last digit but am sure i will find something that will do it

Comment: just add "else: break" in the third for loop. Ill update my answer. If I understand u correctly, u want 877777777 from 111111111? Or do u want 888888888?