# Incrementing list program not incrementing list correctly, need assistance

Tags: python

this my code I got from one of my posts but now need to figure why it's doing something unexpected,i shall describe what it takes and what it gives if it would work properly

```
Input(several examples):
006644322
112222333
Output(examples in order):
008866544
887777666
```

tough when I type for example
this
221111222
it throws that instead and you can see by my two examples the counter is not working correctly, can somebody give ideas of why and what do try and fix I tried tinkering around to no avail
[8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8]

```py
drawbarstring = input("Put your drawbar string here(9 digits): ")
drawbarmain = list(map(int, str(drawbarstring)))

def compute_nums(drawbarmain):
    for i in range(len(drawbarmain)):
        for x in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[x] == 8:
                return drawbarmain

        for j in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[j-1] < 8 and drawbarmain[j] != 0:
                drawbarmain[j] += 1

print(compute_nums(drawbarmain))
```

this is the source code I got it from
[How do you find highest value in the list then increase it with the other values increasing as well expect a value that is set as 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580512/how-do-you-find-highest-value-in-the-list-then-increase-it-with-the-other-values)
I hope somebody can give me an idea, I am enjoying learning python but so far am clueless on why this is happening, edit am sorry for the troubles i caused here is the code i fixed i think i should work now all values work as normal
shout out for the idea that barmar gave me, that worked, no more assistance required, for now, I seem to fixed the issue alone, another edit added my own code in the answers for others to see

Comment: I'm confused. What's the input? What's drawbarstring?

Comment: Use the `max()` function to find the highest number in `drawbarmain`. Subtract that from `8` to get the amount you need to add to each number. Then loop through the list adding that to all the numbers except 0.

Comment: i accepted without testing if first as i was real busy that day, i tough it would work, sorry i guess i will try and fix it myself

Comment: i guess i can aways ask the original person for advice as it was their code

Comment: well i managed to fix a small part but just have to figure why last part is not doing what i need all numbers now scale properly expect last digit but am sure i will find something that will do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223840/discussion-between-iurirolho-and-barmar).

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should post it in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work:

```
def compute_nums(drawbarmain):
    cap = max(drawbarmain) # Find highest value
    inc = 8 - cap # amount to be added to make 8
    for i, val in enumerate(drawbarmain):
        if 0 < val < 8:
            drawbarmain[i] = val + inc # Add to all values other than 0
    return drawbarmain

print(compute_nums([0,0,6,6,4,4,3,2,2]))
print(compute_nums([1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]))
```

Output is:

```
[0, 0, 8, 8, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
[6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

My second result isn't the same as your example, but I think my answer is correct if I understand what it's supposed to do. `3` is the highest number in the list, so it needs to be incremented 5 times to reach `8`, and all the other numbers need to be incremented 5 times as well.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/rGNRJp)

Comment: yet again i made a typo on the example the 2nd one is wrong since my maths aren't that good but i tested your code and seems work so far am going to try it further and then once am sure it works full(i think as you said should work correctly) will probably mark your  answer as my accepted one the first one should be correct the example that is unless my math is failing me like most of the times, edit: i also have a bit of dyslexia so maths and that combined give me issues

Answer (score 0):

this is what i came with

```
drawbarstring = input("Put your drawbar string here(9 digits): ")
drawbarmain = list(map(int, str(drawbarstring)))

def compute_nums(drawbarmain):
    for i in range(len(drawbarmain)):
        for x in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[x] == 8:
                return drawbarmain

        for drawbarcap in range(len(drawbarmain)):
            if drawbarmain[drawbarcap - 1] < 9 and drawbarmain[drawbarcap] != 0:
               drawbarmain[drawbarcap] += 1

print(compute_nums(drawbarmain))
```

it works so I ain't complaining anymore
edit removed variable that was not in use

Comment: Something is missing: `drawbarmain[drawbarcap] +=` ends in the middle of the statement.

Comment: let me fix that code let me see if i can grab the one that passes validation in my end

Comment: should work now i think, somehow i managed to delete that one at the += part

Comment: This seems to be identical to the solution in the question, except the variable `j` is renamed to `drawbarcap`. They both produce the same results: https://ideone.com/lifhXY

Comment: Actually, they produce different results for the second input. Your version: https://ideone.com/kF1XNy

Comment: I see, the difference is `if drawbarmain[j-1] < 8` versus `if drawbarmain[drawbarcap-1] < 9`

Comment: i know by changing the to a 9 worked a bit but am not sure if its broken but with the few tests i did was working semi ok, tough am not exactly sure if its broken but i can aways test if further with more codes i have plenty of random registrations on a list to test with

Comment: I think I finally understand how this code is intended to work, and I think it's correct. It's just a confusing way to do it.